# AngularJS UI Router not working on localhost

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Why is the UI-Router working on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m2v0rusv/1/) and it's not working on my localhost? The localhost link is `http://127.0.0.1:54046/preview/app/index.html`. Am I missing something here? There are no JS errors in the console.

The goal is to load a separate HTML file inside the `ui-view` tag by clicking the links on the header navigation.

HTML

```
<script src="js/bxslider.js"></script>
<script src="js/testim-slider.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="js/target-top.js"></script>-->
<script src="app-test.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/media.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">


<section class="section2">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="header-nav">
            <a ui-sref="main" ><img src="imgs/SCIS-logo2.png" alt="SCIS logo"></a>
            <div class="show-sidenav">
                <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
                  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
                  <a ui-sref="request" onclick="closeNav()">REQUEST AN INTERPRETER</a>
                  <a ui-sref="newinfo" onclick="closeNav()">HEARING/NEW INFO</a>
                  <a ui-sref="deaf" onclick="closeNav()">DEAF CONSUMERS</a>
                  <a ui-sref="recruitment" onclick="closeNav()">INTERPRETER RECRUITMENT</a>
                  <a ui-sref="about" onclick="closeNav()">ABOUT</a>
                </div>
                <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer; float:right;" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
            </div>
            <div class="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a ui-sref="request">REQUEST AN INTERPRETER</a></li>
                    <li><a ui-sref="newinfo" class="arrow">HEARING/NEW INFO</a>
                        <span>
                            <a ui-sref="medical">MEDICAL INTERPRETING</a>
                            <a ui-sref="legal">LEGAL INTERPRETING</a>
                            <a ui-sref="business">BUSINESS INTERPRETING</a>
                            <a ui-sref="eductional">EDUCATIONAL INTERPRETING</a>
                            <a ui-sref="vri">VRI</a>
                        </span>
                    </li>
                    <li><a ui-sref="deaf">DEAF CONSUMERS</a></li>
                    <li><a ui-sref="recruitment">INTERPRETER RECRUITMENT</a></li>
                    <li><a ui-sref="about">ABOUT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<!-- views section -->
<div ui-view>

    Content goes here...

</div>

<!-- footer section -->
<div ng-include="'test-testminoials.html'"></div>
```

JS

```
// JavaScript Document
var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[ "ui.router", "AppCtrls"]);

myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
$stateProvider.state("request", {
    url: "#",
    template: "<p>Request</p>",
    controller: "Ctrl1"
  }).state("newinfo", {
    url: "#",
    template: "<p>New Info</p>",
    controller: "Ctrl2"
    }).state("deaf", {
    url: "#",
    template: "<p>Deaf</p>",
    controller: "Ctrl3"
 }).state("recruitment", {
    url: "#",
    template: "<p>Recruitment</p>",
    controller: "Ctrl4"
     }).state("about", {
    url: "#",
    template: "<p>About</p>",
    controller: "Ctrl5"
     }).state("medical", {
    url: "#",
    template: "<p>Medical</p>",
    controller: "Ctrl6"
     }).state("legal", {
    url: "#",
    template: "<p>Legal</p>",
    controller: "Ctrl7"
     }).state("business", {
    url: "#",
    template: "<p>Business</p>",
    controller: "Ctrl8"
     }).state("educational", {
    url: "#",
    template: "<p>Educational</p>",
    controller: "Ctrl9"
     }).state("vri", {
    url: "#",
    template: "<p>VRI</p>",
    controller: "Ctrl10"
  });
});

var ctrls = angular.module("AppCtrls", []);

ctrls.controller( "Ctrl1", function($scope) {
console.log("Ctrl1 loaded.");
});

ctrls.controller( "Ctrl2", function($scope) {
console.log("Ctrl2 loaded.");
});

ctrls.controller( "Ctrl3", function($scope) {
console.log("Ctrl3 loaded.");
});

ctrls.controller( "Ctrl4", function($scope) {
console.log("Ctrl4 loaded.");
});

ctrls.controller( "Ctrl5", function($scope) {
console.log("Ctrl5 loaded.");
});

ctrls.controller( "Ctrl6", function($scope) {
console.log("Ctrl6 loaded.");
});

ctrls.controller( "Ctrl7", function($scope) {
console.log("Ctrl7 loaded.");
});

ctrls.controller( "Ctrl8", function($scope) {
console.log("Ctrl8 loaded.");
});

ctrls.controller( "Ctrl9", function($scope) {
console.log("Ctrl9 loaded.");
});

ctrls.controller( "Ctrl10", function($scope) {
console.log("Ctrl10 loaded.");
});
```

Comment: Why are the state URL's all just #? That doesn't seem right.

Comment: Ignore the `#` for now. Im trying to test it without loading the html files and display the text only. It seems to be working on JSFiddle, not on my localhost

Comment: When running on localhost is the console log showing anything? Is the initial page loading correctly? Sounds like it maybe some kind of pathing issue with your files then.

Comment: Is it the `angular-ui-router.min.js` and `angular-route.js` that are in the wrong path? They are in the `js` directory.

Comment: It probably doesn't matter, but why are you referencing `angular-route.js` when you are using `ui-router`?

Comment: Because on JSFiddle if I remove either `angular-route.js` or `angular-ui-router.min.js` CDN links then it will not work. Since it works on JSFiddle with both CDN links. I updated the CDN links above and it still doesnt work on my localhost. Any suggestions?

Comment: Make sure the Angular script reference is the first one. If what you have pasted in your question is what you have on your local machine then that may be why it's not working. The order of those script references matters. On the Fiddle you have included the Angular and angular-ui-router as CDN resources in the proper order which would explain why it works there. To demonstrate, check [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xdpLgmL3/1/) where I have reversed the order - it no longer works.

Comment: Your ui-sref must look something like that ui-sref='/state' and then try again

Comment: @SiderTopalov Definitely not true. `ui-sref` refers to the state *name* so a forward slash in there would not be valid.

Comment: @Lex thats true my friend, my bad sorry I’m just typing from my phone is a little bit harder for read ui-sref work with state name not url

Comment: @Lex - I updated the version and uploaded them to the server. Its still not working - view-source:http://christianluneborg.com/clients/scis/index-test.html

Comment: index-test.html ERROR line 12 Status 404 UNFOUND:  https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.14/angular-ui-router.min.js

Comment: The version 1.x of ui-router is very different from the 0.X versions.

Comment: @Luillyfe - can you tell me about this ^^^^ ???

Comment: @georgeawg - So whats the correct CDN link?

Comment: https://unpkg.com/angular-ui-router@0.4.3/release/angular-ui-router.js

Comment: Crap, that still didnt work - http://christianluneborg.com/clients/scis/index-test.html

Answer (score 0):

This must be about the version of AngularJs (1.2.0), ui-router (0.2.10) you are using. Maybe in the JSFiddle you are using a different versions.

You are using version ui-router, there is not `$urlRouterProvider` object but `$urlRouter` (and a lot of other changes), [check the docs](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/0.2.10/#/api/ui.router.router.$urlRouter).

Try to update to the last versions, Angular (1.6.10) and ui-router (1.0.14) then everything would work ok.

Comment: Ok, after I updated the versions, I decided to upload them to my server instead for you to see whats going on. It is still not working. view-source:http://christianluneborg.com/clients/scis/index-test.html

Comment: You're loading two versions of angular-ui-router (v0.2.18 & v0.2.10). Also, you're injecting $urlRouter which doesn't exist in ui.router but I believe in ngRoute which you're not using here. Remove that provider reference and choose 1 version of ui.router like Luillyfe suggested. I would also upgrade your version of angular.min.js to the latest as suggested as well.